# Return SqlConnection as IDbConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am building the DAL layer of my Web API project.
I started implementing the access to database which will be SQL Server.

So when creating some interface IConnectionCreator and implementing it I've got the following problem:

```
public class MsSqlConnectionCreator : IConnectionCreator
{
    public IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Reference to 'ICloneable' claims It is defined in 'System.Runtime' but it couldn't be found

Comment: Where's the reference to `ICloneable`?

Comment: @stuartd Yes, there are two databases which I need to have the access to. SqlConnection inherits from DbConnection (which implements IDbConnection) and implements ICLoneable

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by installing manually System.Data.SqlClient from nuget rather than using Resharper feature for adding packages automatically. In .csproj file I had a physical path to package rather than reference so there was a version conflict.